# Strange url rewriting behavior

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have to redirect all my urls like that:

```
http://www.domain.ltd/foo/bar/var1/var2/var3.html 
to
http://www.other.ltd/search?q=var3&long=0
```

I tried the following:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^foo/bar/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)\.html$ http://www.other.ltd/search?q=$3&long=0
```

It seems to work but I have the last url still sticking to the end of my var3 variable :

```
http://www.other.ltd/search?q=var3/foo/bar/var1/var2/var3.htmllong=0
```

Any clue?

Comment: Do you have other rules or redirects in your htaccess file?

Comment: Yes, but this one comes in first, just after RewriteEngine On &
RewriteBase /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mod_rewrite rule for stripping original query string.

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^foo/bar/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ /search?q=$3&long=0 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: /search?q=$3&long=0, i need to redirect on another domain

Comment: Try this in a different browser to avoid 301 caching and do post your complete .htaccess in question.

Comment: Great to know it worked out. 301 is nasty sometimes for testing.